# Can I notch the end of a piece of fire blocking to accommodate a wire?

Tags: framing, nec, fireblocking

I'm framing a partition wall and a lowered ceiling on one side of that wall. The space above the new, lower ceiling will essentially be attic space, so the inspector said I need fire blocking in the new wall at the new ceiling line.

The electrical work is already done, so I'm wondering if I can notch an end of the blocking to accommodate a wire or two. The alternative would be to remove the wiring, install the blocking, drill a hole, and pull the wiring through. I'd prefer to avoid that extra work, assuming that it's legal and won't compromise safety.

I'm in Clark County, NV if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can notch it. Make it so it does not pinch the wire in anyway, be VERY careful how it is fastened in. Fireblocking foam can be used to fill the rest in while the rest of the fireblocking work is being done.

Comment: I know it is just terminology, but fire stopping is the foam and rock wool if needed, applied around the fire blocking which is wood or drywall. This is my understanding, and the why I used the terms I originally did before the edit by ThreePhaseEel. Of course it is my take on it.